# Why is the NSS PK12UTIL that is being called from a java process reporting bad database?

Tags: java, nss

I do the following:

```
File tmpDir = com.google.common.io.Files.createTempDir();
tmpDir.deleteOnExit();

// determine command based upon OS
String prefix = "pk12util";
String command = String.format(
            "-i %s -d sql:%s -W '' -K ''", 
            cert.getAbsolutePath(), tmpDir.getAbsolutePath());

// run the command
CommandRunner.run(prefix, command);
```

CommandRunner is a wrapper around the java ProcessBuilder. It handles creating the process, returning command output and exit status.

Here is the command being run from the java process and the corresponding output.

> pk12util -i a-typical-tls-cert.p12 -d sql:/tmpdirpath -W '' -K ''
>
> pk12util: function failed: security library: bad database.

When I copy and paste the command I am running from the java process it completes successfully. I verified permissions on the certdir. I even tried running the -N on the tmpDir which yields no resolution. Anyone have any suggestions? I tried to dig through the source code for the pk12util for the error but couldn't find anything pertinent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if anyone else will be doing this but I solved the issue by modifying my CommandRunner from using the ProcessBuilder to use using the Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).  I don't understand why the process builder was failing versus the runtime#exec.